# Flexiquery not working with employee group

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

For my user I have added admingroup and employeegroup and I am trying to run any flexiquery which gives me below exception.

INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/06/02 01:54:13.839 | WARN  [hybrisHTTP5] [10.243.247.193] [DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolved exception caused by handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: while trying to invoke the method de.hybris.platform.catalog.model.CatalogVersionModel.getPk() of a null object loaded from local variable 'ctgVer'; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: while trying to invoke the method de.hybris.platform.catalog.model.CatalogVersionModel.getPk() of a null object loaded from local variable 'ctgVer' (through reference chain: de.hybris.platform.hac.data.dto.SqlSearchResultData["catalogVersionsAsString"])
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/06/02 01:54:13.839 | WARN  [hybrisHTTP5] [10.243.247.193] [DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolved exception caused by handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: while trying to invoke the method de.hybris.platform.catalog.model.CatalogVersionModel.getPk() of a null object loaded from local variable 'ctgVer'; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: while trying to invoke the method de.hybris.platform.catalog.model.CatalogVersionModel.getPk() of a null object loaded from local variable 'ctgVer' (through reference chain: de.hybris.platform.hac.data.dto.SqlSearchResultData["catalogVersionsAsString"])

If I remove the employeegroup from my user then it is working fine. Could someone help me to understand what is the issue here.

Kind regards,
CHOLA

Comment: Can you share the SQL query?

Comment: it is not happening for specific query. this exception occurring for all querys. Eg select * from {employee}

Comment: Where are you running the query? Is it in HAC? Maybe employeegroup doesn't have access to the Type?

Comment: Yes, I am running the query in hac. So what permission I need to add for employeegroup where to add

Comment: Have you tried giving the user access to the Type?